# (Windows 10) Can a script be used to change the preferred graphics adapter for a certain application?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, power-management, integrated-graphics

I have a 4k screen on my laptop, so sometimes certain desktop applications like Chrome take more GPU power to run than my integrated graphics is comfortable with. I want to be able to run apps such as this with integrated graphics most of the time for power savings, but switch to dedicated graphics easily on-demand (without needing to edit per-application settings in the NVidia Control Panel or similar).

I am able to easily make macros that run an executable/script. Having the app switch GPUs without needing to be closed would be a plus, but it's not required.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If your program can support Display:n in it's setup.  Chrome doesn't.
Or you set your primary display to the good GPU.
Or you use NVIDIA software.  If it's missing something, let me know in the comments.

Comment: What is Display:n?

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer my question; I want to know if there is a way to change preferred graphics adapter that does not involve manually clicking through a UI.

Comment: OpenGL and Direct3D supports Display:0 etc for the virtual device name.  I am getting more details, hang in there.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/bysdyn/how_do_i_force_chromeexe_to_use_a_specific_gpu_on/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403833/automatically-open-browser-window-on-another-monitor

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-the-position-and-size-54853527

The latter was used by one of our team.